# mongodb limit server memory consumption

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'm testing running monbodb on the kubernetes platform where I can limit the resources used by the running container.

Say I set the memory limit to 256Mb. The problem is that for example while making backup memory consumption increases to the limit and container gets restarted by kubernetes.

So the question is is there a way to limit mongodb memory consumption for my case so that it would not cause the crush by exeeding memory limit set by platform.

I could of course increase the limit but I'm interested in a principal solution and would like to understand this process better because I don't really now how memory consumed by mongodb and container os. Is it possible to tune mongodb/underlying linux os to work inside existing limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits that you have set are good enough for a monogodb pod, these are the limits used by the [community](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/blob/5af2d884f4c496cd29e6b38a81b975a54ebba645/stable/mongodb/values.yaml#L39) as well.

The only way I think you can get around this for backups is to increase the memory limits, but still it might fail, because in other places on stackoverflow people have experienced OOM killing on VMs with memory of giga bytes. MongoDB basically tries to eat any and every memory that is made available to it.

Also there are other ways to backup mongodb: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/how-to-backup-large-mongodb-database

I am not sure how this aligns in the k8s world.